# Stripe not show response data during enter invalid card details in PHP

Tags: php, sdk, stripe-payments, jsonresponse, stripe-payment-intent

I add a Stripe SDK for the payment gateway. which works fine when I enter the correct card details. but if I enter the wrong card details like enter the wrong card number it doesn't show me any response. when I try to understand I found that when I enter the wrong card details it doesn't create a token. I think that's the problem but I need help to find out why stripe doesn't show me any response in PHP. during wrong card details.

here is my PHP code:-

```
if(isset($_REQUEST)){
  $cardno = $_POST['cardno'];
  $cardname = $_POST['cardno';
  $cardmonth = $_POST['cardmonth'];
  $cardyear = $_POST['cardyear'];
  $cardcvv = $_POST['cardcvv'];

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
                $stripeSecret = 'strpe_api_key';

                \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripeSecret);
            
            $token = \Stripe\Token::create(array(
                  "card" => array(
                    "number" => $cardno,
                    "exp_month" => $cardmonth,
                    "exp_year" => $cardyear,
                    "cvc" => $cardcvv
                  )
                ));
            //echo "10";
                $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
                  [

                    'description' => "Package Subscription",
                    'shipping' => [
                            'name' => 'sam',
                            'phone'=> '0123456789',

                            'address' => [
                            'line1' => '510 Townsend St',
                            'postal_code' => '98140',
                            'city' => 'San Francisco',
                            'state' => 'CA',
                            'country' => 'US',
                            ],//address ands
                    ],//shipping ends
                    'amount' => round(10.00 * 100),
                    'currency' => 'usd',
                        "source" => $token,
                  ]
                ));
     }
```

Anyone know how check this so please help me out.

Comment: That's a legacy integration you can't and shouldn't use for a new project and has major PCI compliance implications. Please use Stripe's current integrations of Checkout/PaymentElement instead, they display errors on the frontend in a more effective way. https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment

Comment: sorry I can't understand.